# Accessing React component wrapped in higher order component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I know there are similar questions but none of them have an answer which is puzzling cause the problem should affect a lot of people using component wrapping.

Say I have a component wrapped in a wrapper like Spring from React-Motion. **What is an elegant *react-ish* way of accessing the wrapped react component e.g. in a mouse event handler placed higher in the structure?**

Without the wrapper, in the examples I've seen it's done by binding child's id to the handler in parent's render method and then accessing the child by parent.refs[id]. I can think of at least a few ugly workarounds like:

- passing the same ref id to the wrapper and having a helper method which returns this.refs[id].refs[id]
- putting the wrapper lower in the structure, eg. putting `Spring` inside my child component and not wrapping the child in it.
- duplicating the child props on the wrapper (which doesn't give access to the real thing though).

but is there a typical solution to that? I feel that having a wrapper which just adds some functionality shouldn't break the communication between parent and child so easily.

Comment: Why does the handler need a DOM reference (via refs) to the child? With `bind()` you can send as much child state to the parent as needed. In general, the only time you need refs is if you need to do something DOM native.